# Using the ServiceManager in a non ZF2-MVC environment

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm currently using ZF2 as a library.

Currently, I'm pretty much cascading an injection of my database object into the controllers via the route. Obviously, had I started to use zend framework 2 in the first place, I would have stored the DB into an instance of ServiceManager and sent that through instead.

Anyway, I have a **service** class which is full of static method. These methods are basic, and all they do is report back information. They're pretty much brainless. A method I have: `UserService::getCurrentUser()` is meant to return an object containing the current user information.

However, one problem I'm dealing with, is that inside this method, I'm doing this:

```
    $user = new objects\user();
    $user->setUserId(self::currentUserId());


    $data = new \model\dao\users($database);
    $user = $data->loadUser($user);

    return $user;
```

I seem to now have a black hole in that I have no way of getting the $database, in this case, an instance of `Zend\Db\Adapter`.

Any ideas how I can plug this hole?

Comment: The service manager is agnostic. Why not define your current database implementation as a service as service? ... and your user class. I'm a fan of Dependency Injection... I would even be using the service manager to inject the db credentials and create your database connection